# Dune SQL column with running totals and group by

Tags: sql, dune

I am trying to write a Dune analytics query using their native SQL language using the Dune v2 engine. I'm not very experienced in writing SQL queries - it's been 10+ years.

At the moment I have written the following query, which works as intended (you can see my [public dashboard](https://dune.com/zkoh13/top-nft-collections)):

```
select
  collection,
  count(collection) as num_transactions
from
  nft.trades
where
  blockchain = "ethereum"
  and collection <> ""
  and block_time >= '{{from_date}}'
group by 1
order by 2 desc
```

This returns a table like so:

```
collection                  | num_transactions
----------------------------------------------
GrandpaApes                 | 4666
Ethereum Name Service (ENS) | 4545
OpenSea Collection          | 2319
```

As you can see from the dashboard, this correctly returns NFT trades grouped by collection in descending order of the number of transactions.

What I'm trying to do is to add a column that contains a running cumulative total of `num_transactions` - let's call this `tot_transactions`. The result I want is something like this:

```
collection                  | num_transactions | tot_transactions
-----------------------------------------------------------------
GrandpaApes                 | 4666             | 4666
Ethereum Name Service (ENS) | 4545             | 9211
OpenSea Collection          | 2319             | 11530
```

I tried to do this by amending the query as below but it throws an error; I've read a [bunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211329/add-a-cumulative-running-total-column) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439138/running-total-by-grouped-records-in-table) the other SQL questions on SO but so far I haven't been able to get any of them to work. How should I be writing my query to make this succeed in Dune?

```
select
  collection,
  count(collection) as num_transactions,
  sum(count(collection)) as tot_transactions
from
  nft.trades
where
  blockchain = "{{blockchain}}"
  and collection <> ""
  and block_time >= '{{from_date}}'
group by 1
order by 2 desc
```

Error message:

```
Error: {42000} [Simba][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: It is not allowed to use an aggregate function in the argument of another aggregate function. Please use the inner aggregate function in a sub-query.
```

Note: I can see that it's telling me I can't use an aggregate inside another aggregate (I assume this means I can't use `count()` inside `sum()`) but I tried using a subquery and I wasn't sure how to get that to work either (apologies - I no longer have the version of the query I wrote that has the subquery in it).

Answer (score 1):

Error message is coming from Apache Hive SQL.  Looking at the documentation for Apache Hive SQL, they say they support windowing functions, so replace your `sum(count(collection))` with

```
Sum(count(collection)) Over (Group By collection Order By count(collection) Rows Between Unbounded Preceding and Current Row)
```

Yes, it's quite verbose.

If that does not work then wrap this query inside a second query where you use this in a windowing sum

Comment: It would be `PARTITION BY collection` as first term after `OVER`